# If two class inherit an static field, will the objects of those classes share the same value?

Tags: c#, inheritance

Is it possible that different objects of different classes can use one shared item among themselves (e.g for providing some information on the fly) or better a means of communication between different objects of two different classes ?

```
Class Base 
{
   public static string SomeThing = "Shared With All";
}
Class Der1 :Base
{
     public void DoSomeThing()
     {
          SomeThing = "SomeThing Goes in here...";
     }
}

Class Der2 :Base
{
     public void DoSomeThingElse()
     {
          Console.WriteLine"(SomeThing);
     }
}

....
{
    Der1 dr1 = new Der1();
    dr1.DoSomeThing();  
    Der2 dr2 = new Der2();
    dr2.DoSomeThingElse(); //shows 'SomeThing Goes in here...'  
}
```

If it helps more, I am trying to create a designer of some kind and so I need to get track of all controls and their associations on the designer.   Actually there are only two objects at the moment (one called transaction and the other is called place, different places can be associated with different transactions, and this association is done by the user clicking on one place and pointing to the other transactions (have you seen `Proteus`? something like that).

So this approach will help me know which object is referring which other object and thus and association between the two can be easily spotted and saved.

Comment: There is more than one thing you wish to achieve : a)  one shared item among themselves (In java, we do this using static variables) b) ( e.g for providing some information on the fly ) Is this going to be a web app ? Just a desktop app ?  c)a means of communication between different objects of two different classes ? Method calls ?

Comment: This is a desktop application , and it has a designer in-which users can place some objects of different kinds and associate them . in order to find out which object is associated with other i thought of that solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The static field isn't really inherited in the same way as normal fields are. There's still just *one* static field, `Base.SomeThing`. Both of your derived classes are referring to the same field: if *anything* changes `Base.SomeThing`, *everything* that accesses that field will see the change.

Comment: Thank you.I updated my question to explained more about the actual scenario.I would appreciate any more guidance on this subject.

Comment: @Hossein: It's not really clear what that has to do with static fields. It sounds like basically want the `User` class to have a `List<PlaceTransactionAssociation>` where a `PlaceTransactionAssociation` has both a place and a transaction...

Comment: Yes thats it, but prior to that i need to get the both sides identified, and this is where i am stuck , i need to know which two objects our user associated together.if i have a static variable shared between these two classes,when user clicks on say a place i get the place id and when it clicks on any transaction, i have the place and now i get the transaction and its done.So i am looking for a better way of achieving the same result

Comment: @Hossein: When the user clicks on a place, you should keep that information within the UI somewhere - for example, your list view may well have some notion of a selected item. It's hard to know what your code is like from this, but it sounds like you're now asking a *radically* different one from the original. I suggest you ask a new SO question if you're still confused.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you've invented a global variable :) It is also almost always a sign of bad design. Try solving your task differently.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but think carefully about communicating in this way inside the class. There is no good way to account for concurrency issues and very hard to debug if the value is set multiple places.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `static` var's or share stuff using `setter` and `getter`. These are basic operators in OOP.

Answer (score 1):

A static field belongs to the class that declares it. Any subclasses of that class gets access to that one static field.

There are some caveats here. Declaring a static variable on a Generic class means that one copy of that variable exists for each closed type of that generic. Here's an example to clarify

```
public class StaticGenericTest<T>
{
  private static int count=0;
  public StaticGenericTest()
  {
     count++;
  }
}
```

If you instantiate a `StaticGenericTest<int>` and a `StaticGenericTest<string>` they would have different values for count. However a subclass of `StaticGenericTest<int>` would share count with all other subclasses of `StaticGenericTest<int>`.

Also you'll get funny behavior using the `ThreadStatic` attribute (because you'll get one copy of count per thread) and/or [static constructors](http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/06/static-constructors-part-one/).

As someone mentioned, Static fields are global state and should be protected as such and used with caution.